# Cuda returns wrong value from __device__ function when cos is used

Tags: c, memory-management, cuda, nvidia, trigonometry

I'm trying to run this code on nvidia GPU and it returns strange values. It consist of two modules `main.cu` and `exmodul.cu` (**listed bellow**). For building I'm using:

```
nvcc -dc -arch sm_35 main.cu
nvcc -dc -arch sm_35 exmodul.cu
nvcc     -arch sm_35 -lcudart -o main main.o exmodul.o
```

If I run that I obtained strange last line!!! **gd must be 1**.

```
result=0
result=0
result=0
result=0
gd=-0.5
```

- When I change `1.0` in `exmodul.cu` to number greater than
  `1.000000953` or bellow `0.999999999999999945`, it return proper
  result.
- When I change `1.1` in `exmodul.cu` it also fails except value `1.0`.
- Behavior doesn't depend on constant `2.0` in the same module.
- When I use another function instead of `cos` like `sin` or `exp` it works properly.
- Use of `double q = cos(1.1);` has no effect.
- When I copy function `extFunc()` to module `main.cu` it works properly.
- If I uncomment `*gd=1.0;` in `main.cu` it returns correct `1.0`.

Tested on Nvidia GT750M and GeForce GTX TITAN Black. (on GT750M returns different value `gd=6.1232329394368592e-17` but still wrong). OS: Debian Jessie.

```
$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2013 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Thu_Mar_13_11:58:58_PDT_2014
Cuda compilation tools, release 6.0, V6.0.1
```

Have you got any idea what is wrong?

Thanks, Lukas

---

main.cu

```
#include <stdio.h>   // printf
#include "exmodul.h" // extFunc

__global__ void mykernel(double*gd);
void deviceCheck();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double gd, *d_gd;
    cudaMalloc(&d_gd, sizeof(double)); deviceCheck();
    mykernel<<<1,1>>>(d_gd);           deviceCheck();
    cudaMemcpy(&gd, d_gd, sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
                                       deviceCheck();
    cudaFree(d_gd);                    deviceCheck();
    fprintf(stderr,"gd=%.17g\n",gd);
    return 0;
}

void deviceCheck()
{
    cudaError_t result = cudaSuccess;
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    result = cudaGetLastError();
    fprintf(stderr,"result=%d\n",result); fflush(stderr);
}

__global__ void mykernel(double *gd)
{
    *gd = extFunc();
    //*gd=1.0;
    __syncthreads();
    return;
}
```

exmodul.cu

```
#include "exmodul.h"

__device__ double extFunc()
{
    double q = 1.1;
    q = cos(q);
    if(q<2.0) { q = 1.0; }
    return q;
}
```

exmodul.h

```
__device__ double extFunc();
```

Comment: the range of the return value from cos() is -1 ... +1.   so this line: 'if(q<2.0) { q = 1.0; }' always results in q == 1.0

Comment: this line: 'printf(stderr,"gd=%.17g\n",gd);' is incorrect, it should be: 'fprintf(stderr,"gd=%.17g\n",gd);' // notice the different function call  Also, the value in 'gd' is always 1.0 and the format conversion has not characters left of the decimal point to print the 1.  That is why all the print values are 0

Comment: user3629249 : Thanks.

Including `math.h` is not necessary, see [1].

I expect that it must return q==1 because of `-1 < cos <+1`, but it doesn't work. And I don't know why..

`fprintf` was my mistake made during copying code to here. 

[1] https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/792656/cuda-programming-and-performance/linking-device-code/

Comment: user3629249: Format `%.17g`, please read [1]: number before `.` is optional and "The value is not truncated even if the result is larger.". See first point in discussion, that's not the problem. There is no problem with printing return value `2`.
[1] http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue, but I am on Windows and use CUDA 6.5. The different values returned on different GPUs suggest that CUDA API calls are failing. Your error checking doesn't seem to be as tight as possible, you may want to try directly checking the return status of API functions, an pre-launch plus post-launch kernel errors, as shown, for example, [here](http://choorucode.com/2011/03/02/how-to-do-error-checking-in-cuda/).

Comment: Thanks for the article. I used these checks, but **no error occurred and nothing changed**. I'm not using CUDA 6.5 because it hasn't been packed for debian yet.

Comment: @Luuuucky Is Debian a supported OS for CUDA 6.0, according to NVIDIA? If not, you are on your own, as proper CUDA operation with the OS hasn't been verified by NVIDIA. You may want to inquire on a Debian-specific forum or mailing list. I suspect the issue is local to your system (bad install etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce problematic behavior on a supported config (CUDA 6.5, CentOS 6.2, K40).

When I switched from CUDA 6.5 to CUDA 7 RC, the problem went away.

The problem also did not appear to be reproducible on an older config (CUDA 5.5, CentOS 6.2, M2070)

I suggest switching to CUDA 7 RC to address this issue.  I suspect an underlying bug in the compilation process that has been fixed already.

Comment: Thank you. I submitted that as a bug no nvidia.